# how to compress data using perl dbi with mysql

Tags: mysql, perl

I am using perl dbi connection to pull data remotely. I am looking to compress the data if possible.
Is there a way to do a file compression over the net with perl dbi for mysql?

Here is my snippet for getting data:

```
     my $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT UUID(), '$node', 1, 2, 3, 4, vts FROM $tblist");
     $sth->execute();
     while (my($uid, $hostnm,$1,$2,$3,$upd,$vts) = $sth->fetchrow_array() ) { 
       print $gzip_fh "rec^A$uid^Ehost^A$hostnm^E1^A$1^E2^A$2^E3^A$3^E4^A$upd^Evts^A$vts^D";
     }
     $sth->finish;
```

Answer (score 2):

Best option will be to use [prepared statements](http://p3rl.org/DBI#prepare); with this, once you have compiled the statement once you just have to send the arguments over the wire each time you need to run the queries.

The example here shows how to perform a simple prepare, if you are going to utilize the same query over and over again you should keep your `$sth` which you can continue to call `$sth->execute()` on with new variables.  The reason this cuts down on your network traversal is because you're not sending the query each time you run `$sth->execute($var)`, instead you're just passing an ID for the prepared statement and the variables that go into the `?` placeholders.

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("select * from table where column=?");
$sth->execute($var);
```

Comment: I am using the prepare statement now. I think the next thing do is test this and see how fast I get it come over the wire.

Comment: @jdamae: Just make sure that when you are doing preparedStatements you are saving the preparedStatements; I've seen many instances where people will perform the query from the preparedStatement and then throw it away.  Just making a general observation over things that I've seen.

Comment: @Suroot- thanks for your input. I am not much of a perl expert. Can you elaborate on that? I will post my code. thanks.

Comment: @jdamae: I have updated to explain better how to use the prepared statements and what I mean when I say you shouldn't throw away the prepared statement handlers.

Comment: @Suroot- thank you for your help. I will try your suggestions. Thanks again.